# How to set specific language in iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator

I've done this so far:

[image: Imgur]

But I still get language set to english:

[image]

Does anyone know if I'm missing something?

---

edit:

If I do this:

```
- (void)logAllLocales
{
   NSLocale *curentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
   NSArray *locales = [[NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
   for (NSString *locale in locales)
   NSLog(@"locale '%@' is: %@'", locale, [curentLocale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:locale]);
}
```

result:

‘sv’ is: Swedish’

‘sv_FI’ is: Swedish (Finland)’

‘sv_SE’ is: Swedish (Sweden)’

I'll get three swedish locale options so technically "sv" should do. But I also tested the other options without luck.

But if the simultor need a reset to change the Lanugage then I think my question is answeded. It's not possible with arguments passed in on launch. =)

Comment: hej, in the SIMULATOR (your second image), you have "English", you should set Swedish in the simulator.  (Also: simply try it in your iPhone.)

Comment: you have the option in front of your eyes (2nd screenshot), change to whatever you want

Comment: Well the thing is that I deploy to simulator a lot. And before every deploy I usually want to clean the whole simulator with a hoy-key: I've connected "Reset Content and Settings..." to cmd+K. This makes the simulator reset back to english language even if I set it explicitly via the very obvious way pointed out below. (Settings > General > International) I really want it to be an argument passed on launch. Its a very tedious way to do it manually every single time, especially when Im working only with swedish, norweigan and danish at the moment. =)

Comment: Assuming you localized to 'Swedish (Sweden)', you need to use either `sv-SE` or `(Swedish (Sweden))` as the key, otherwise it will not match because your localization is set to `sv-SE` rather than simply `sv`!

Comment: Additionally, don't expect the carrier text to change in this situation - that requires a simulator reboot. When you pass in the parameters to the launch, it changes the locale and language for the app only, and not for the entire system. There are other (googlable) methods for changing the simulator's overall language

Comment: I got this working by adding double quotes around the language. I.e. -AppleLanguages "(fr)". But obviously as said above this is only for the app, the OS is unaffected.

Answer (score 5):

It's the same procedure you use in physical device. 
Go in **Settings > General > International** and change the **Language** from *English* to *Swedish*

---

### Edit based on 3rd comment in the question

> Well the thing is that I deploy to simulator a lot. And before every deploy I usually want to clean the whole simulator with a hoy-key: I've connected "Reset Content and Settings..." to cmd+K. This makes the simulator reset back to english language even if I set it explicitly via the very obvious way pointed out below. (Settings > General > International) I really want it to be an argument passed on launch. Its a very tedious way to do it manually every single time, especially when Im working only with swedish, norweigan and danish at the moment. =)

Try to replace in Localizable.string (En) the entire content with the Swedish / Norvegian and Danish content. So the simulator is in English, read from English string file but show content in another language.

Comment: Well thanks but that I already knew. =) I really wants to pass as argument on launch to not have to do it manually every single time.

Comment: Obiouvsly you have to save the English momentary in another file. This is a solution for the development, no for the release. When you release the app put English in English, Swedish in Swedish an so on.

Comment: I guess Ive come to the conclusion that its not possible with argument passed to simulator on launch. The language in the app is actually iusing the correct language which is the important thing. =)

Answer (score 1):

I have Xcode 13.2.1 & was able to configure the app language by modifying the scheme options.

- Edit Scheme > Options > Application Language

The app will launch with the language settings you provide.
No need to change it manually from the simulator setting.

[image: scheme options]

---

Credits:

- https://medium.com/swlh/app-localization-in-swift-ios-swift-guide-baa2c2e4298e

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right, to change the simulator language you just need to change it from the "language" option on simulator screen shot that you have attached. tap it and select the language that you want.

Comment: Yes thats what I want to do but automatically when I deploy. If I do it more than 500 times a day then it can be quite annoying. =)

Answer (score 0):

As said in my last edit. I think this is not possible since the simulator must reset to actually change system language.